# How can i pass data by onclick chilld component to parent component react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How can I pass data from child component to parent component by using onclick event.

I usually used this code for my apps . whenever I click button , I saw  in my parent component CreateEmail it’s called function :

```
ƒ (selectedItem) {
        var listofdata = _this.state.listofdata;
    }

     dddd = (selectedItem) => {
        const { listofdata } = this.state;

        const newList = [...listofdata];


        const itemIndex = newList.findIndex(item => item.name === selectedItem.name);

        if (itemIndex > -1) {
          newList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        } else {
          newList.push(selectedItem);
        }

        this.setState({
          listofdata: newList
        })

      }

    <CreateEmail dddd={this.dddd}/>

       <button onClick={() => this.dddd(item)} className=" btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" >+</button>
```

I need to get only data when I click on the button .

Comment: Keep the data you want to pass in the state of the parent component. Update it from the child. It will automatically trigger rerender of the parent.

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: @Poran You can define the shared state in the Parent Component and pass that using Props so that child components can access them and modify them.

For example check this out: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Comment: Just do this, - `<button onClick={() => this.props.dddd(item)} className=" btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" >+</button>`

Comment: this button is my child components

Comment: `dddd` is a function in parent and `CreateEmail` is your child component in which you have button and from that button you need to call `dddd` from parent correct?

Comment: I need to pass ddd function inside createmail component . ex: test = ()=this.props.dd(‘“Test”)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your `parent.js`

```
class parent extends React.Component{

  dddd = (selectedItem) => {
        const { listofdata } = this.state;

        const newList = [...listofdata];


        const itemIndex = newList.findIndex(item => item.name === selectedItem.name);

        if (itemIndex > -1) {
          newList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        } else {
          newList.push(selectedItem);
        }

        this.setState({
          listofdata: newList
        })

      }
render(){
  return(
     <CreateEmail dddd={this.dddd}/> //child component added
  )
}
}
```

And this is your child component `CreateEmail.js`,

```
class CreateEmail extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        item: '';
      }
    }
    handleClick = () =>{
         //here you should have logic to get data which you want to pass to parent component either maintain in state
        this.props.dddd(this.state.item)
    }
    render(){
       return(
           <button onClick={() => this.handleClick} className=" btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light" >+</button>
       )
    }
}
```